# Where should I look when my .vimrc is overridden

Tags: vim

I wrote

```
set tw=0
```

into my .vimrc file.

But when I verify options with

```
:set
```

it's still

```
textwidth=78
```

Why ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use :

```
:verbose set tw?
```

Which should tell you where it was last setted, for example :

```
textwidth=80
    Last set from ~/.vimrc
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just grep through your .vim directory for it?

Comment: Thanks, I always forget to verify the directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you have modelines enabled, vim will read the last few lines of the file for vim settings, so check that as well.